# In SSIS, how can one simply ignore records that Lookup identifies as not a match?

Tags: ssis

In my current SSIS data flow task, I feed my data flow into a Lookup tool. Matches are inserted into one table and non-matches are inserted into another table.

I did it this way because this is what I was able to learn from the available tutorials at the time.

[image: Excerpt of data flow]

However, it seems wasteful because I don't really want the non-matched records at all. Is there a way to tell SSIS to discard the non-matched records entirely rather than store them in a table?

The lookup dialog doesn't appear to give me an option for "ignore non-matches."

Is there some way to achieve this desired behavior?

- If lookup = match, insert matched records into table (as currently done)
- If lookup not a match, ignore (or discard) non-matched records

[image: Lookup dialog]

Comment: Have you tried selecting "Ignore failure" and/or removing the "Non-matched records to non-match table" destination?

Comment: That was one of the first things I did. It's not a "failure", so the end result was not what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave `Redirect rows to no match output` as you currently have specified.

Select the "non-matched" branch and delete the destination.

Done.

Really, that's it. The rows will still be in the memory buffers of your data flow but they won't carry to the Match destination as they'll be logically segmented.

Personally, I have a Row Count wired up so I can count the original Rows, the matched rows and the unmatched rows. It helps me audit how the package has performed over time but there's nothing wrong with not using an output stream from a component.

Comment: I can't believe it is that simple. The only thing I'd add to make the answer more complete: (1) in the menu, select `SSIS > Variables` and create a variable name so that the RowCount tool has a place to put the row count value. (I called mine `NoMatchCount`); (2) double-click the RowCount control and select the variable you created (my variable appears as `User:NoMatchCount`). Click ok.